# Not able to add background color or image on the form displaying a list of buttons-Blackberry

Tags: java, layout, blackberry, button, user-interface

I am working on the following code which has a welcome form with 6 buttons.

On click of each of those buttons it opens a new form.

```
   class MyAPP extends UiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            UiApplication instance = new MyAPP();
            instance.enterEventDispatcher();
    }
    private ButtonField btntest,btntest1,btntest2,btntest3,btntest4,btntest5;
    public MyAPP() {

            MainScreen testScreen = new MainScreen();


            final LabelField field  = new LabelField("Company",LabelField.FIELD_HCENTER | LabelField.NON_FOCUSABLE)
    {
        protected void paint(Graphics g)
            {       
                     g.clear();
                    g.drawRect(0,0, 50, 50);
                    int oldColor = g.getColor();
                    g.setColor(Color.DODGERBLUE);
                    g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getPreferredWidth(), this.getPreferredHeight());
                    g.setColor(oldColor);
                    g.drawRect(100, 100, 50, 50);
                    super.paint(g);
             }
    };
    testScreen.setTitle(field);


    //Add status field to bottom of screen in blue color

    final LabelField field1  = new LabelField(" Copyright")
    {
        protected void paint(Graphics g)
            {       
                  //   g.clear();
                    g.drawRect(0,0, 50, 50);
                    int oldColor = g.getColor();
                    g.setColor(Color.DODGERBLUE);
                    g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getPreferredWidth(), this.getPreferredHeight());
                    g.setColor(oldColor);
                    g.drawRect(100, 100, 50, 50);
                    super.paint(g);
             }

    };
    //field1.setFontColor(Color.WHITE);

        btntest1 = new ButtonField("Customer",ButtonField.FIELD_HCENTER | ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);  
        btntest = new ButtonField("Bills  ",ButtonField.FIELD_HCENTER | ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
        btntest2 = new ButtonField("Ledger ",ButtonField.FIELD_HCENTER | ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK); 
        btntest3 = new ButtonField("Receipts",ButtonField.FIELD_HCENTER | ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);


         btntest1.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener()
      {
           public void fieldChanged(Field field,int context) 
           {
              pushScreen(new NextScreen2());
           }
      });




     btntest.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener()
      {
           public void fieldChanged(Field field,int context) 
           {
              pushScreen(new NextScreen1());
           }
      });


      btntest2.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener()
      {
           public void fieldChanged(Field field,int context) 
           {
              pushScreen(new NextScreen4());
           }

      });
```

I have also tried putting an image bitmap that lies on the center of the form but it doesnt appear anywhere.

In the present code i have added title and status fields and also i have added

1. An image to the top of the screen with welcome caption.
2. There are 6 buttons that are center aligned.

Is it because the buttons are in center and there is no space left for the color implementation to take place that it is not visible?Also i am unable to add an image that stays as a background to the entire form.Anyone aware on a solution please guide.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code:

```java
// initialize background
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("myImage");
Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(bm);

// getMainManager(), apply background
testScreen.getMainManager().setBackground(bg);
```